# How do I kill the java process using given name?

Tags: java

I am running my java class as below and now I want kill this java process with out using PID. I want to use dharsha. Is this possible? If not tell how can I kill the java process programmatically or command in windows

```
start "dharsha" java Main
```

Answer (score 1):

you can run a taskkill

```
taskkill /f /im javaw.exe
or
taskkill /f /im java.exe
```

I think this one is more efficient:

```
wmic process where "name like '%java%'" delete
```

For specific application:

```
FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims= " %%G IN ('jps -l') DO IF %%H=myMainclass taskkill /F /PID %%G

//myMainClass stands for your application's main class
```

Comment: if we runs many java process we can not this . I need kill only related to my work and also we can not delete using process id its randomly created by OS. and see there i have added process name but i not able get that and kill

Comment: Actually `start` names the *window* not the process, but `taskkill` can filter on that slightly less conveniently `taskkill /f /fi "windowtitle eq dharsha"`

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I added something for specific application